# jQuery works in Chrome but not Safari

Tags: jquery, safari

I have a website I built that uses jQuery to calculate the current age of dogs based of their birth date. The jQuery works in google chrome but does not work in safari and I haven't been able to figure out why.

```
function puppyAge(){
  let d = new Date()
  let dob = $(`input[name=puppy-age]`).val()
  dob = new Date(dob)
  let age = Math.floor((d-dob)/ (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
  if (age == 1) {
    $(`input[name=puppy-age]`).after(`<p>${age} week</p>`)
  }
  else {
    $(`input[name=puppy-age]`).after(`<p>${age} weeks</p>`)
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  galleryNavigarion(); // scroll page down to each puppy
  parentAge();         // calculate how old (in years) from DOB
  puppyAge();          // calculate how old (in Months) from DOB
})
```

The output is giving me "NaN weeks" on safari, but on chrome it gives me the right number.

Comment: Most likely due to the date format in the `dob` string. What is the value you're entering in there?

Comment: It's not clear which string do you use for date input. However try to parse your date string before usage: `const inputValue = $('input[name=puppy-age]').val()` and then
`const dob = Date.parse(inputValue)`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here.

It would help if you included the HTML as it's not 100% clear whether the `name="puppy-age"` input is a number or a date, but I'm guessing it's a number. Another good idea when asking a question on Stackoverflow, is to make your code as readable as possible for others. This includes getting rid of the call of functions that you don't include in the code, and that doesn't have any tie to the issue :) *(`parentAge` and `galleryNavigarion`)*

When you use `$().val()` you get the value as a string. You should wrap it in the JavaScript function `parseInt()` to get the value as an integer.

Secondly, you write `dob = new Date(dob)`, which with `dob` fx being 10 would result in the date of Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100. So if you want the date today subtracted with the age of the dog, you could do;

```
var d = new Date();
dob = new Date(d.getFullYear() - dob, 1);
```

The second parameter being `1` *(month)* is important, as JavaScript otherwise don't know that the first parameter you're passing is a year, not milliseconds.

Thirdly, you might want to look at `Math.floor` as it in my tests resulted in getting `0` a lot.